# Text Overflow Correction

Tags: javascript, css

i have a div with limited height and limited width. It should display numbers. But beacuse of its limited width i would like to clip its text. But using 'ellipsis' it gets faulty.you can try it yourself.

```
<div id="numdiv">1000</div>


#numdiv
{
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
top:-80px;
left:103px;
text-align:left;
font-size:15px;
height:20px;
overflow:hidden; 
white-space:nowrap; 
text-overflow:ellipsis;
 width:18px;
border:1px solid #494949;
 background:#FF9900;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 border-radius:3px;
}
```

Either i should get it correctly displayed or a '+' sign to the overflow would be nice.Please help me. I could also use JS to dynamically check for the length. I guess !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `text-overflow: ellipsis` use:

```
text-overflow:clip;
```

See Here:
http://jsbin.com/urubed/3/

**EDIT**

if you want it to dynamically change without JS change `position: relative` to:

```
position: absolute;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: no its not the thing.Like, if the number is greater than 99 the width of the #numdiv gets a bit bigger.Its JS, i guess.